# Powershell Replace multiple lines

Tags: powershell

I need to remove the following block in multiple files

```
resources:
  limits:
    memory: 300Mi
  requests:
    memory: 128Mi
```

I'm trying with the following code with no success:

```
Get-ChildItem '..\.\Helm-Charts\containerizedcomponents\values.yaml' -Recurse | ForEach {
     (Get-Content $_) | ForEach  {$_ -Replace 'resources:
  limits:
    memory: 300Mi
  requests:
    memory: 128Mi', ''} | Set-Content $_
}
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Instead of using dubious string replacements, I would [use a yaml parser](https://github.com/cloudbase/powershell-yaml)

Comment: `get-content -raw` to get more than one line, but I would make backup copies first.  There's also taking `\r` and `\n` into account.  Set-content also adds a newline by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example.  But watch the details.  I'm assuming windows text with `\r\n` line endings.  I would backup the files first.  Command line and scripts may work differently; take out the `\r` in a script.  This is very fussy.

```
"one`r
two`r
three`r
four`r
" | set-content file.txt -nonewline


(get-content -raw file.txt) -replace 'two\r
three\r
' | set-content -NoNewline file2.txt


get-content file2.txt

one
four
```

Comment: get-content -raw did the job, thanks!